# Windows .bat pairwise loop process?

Tags: windows, batch-file, gdal

I'm new to command line work and not sure if it's possible to do what I want in this .bat file...

I have image pairs in infrared and natural color named like this "001_x_y_NIR.tif" and "001_x_y_RGB.tif" where the leading three digits serve to identify the image pairs.

This code splices image bands from two 3 band input files into one 4 band image file.

What I want is to have the following code run through a folder containing several NIR/RGB image pairs such that it does the batch on 001_x_y_NIR.tif and 001_x_y_RGB.tif and then does it on 002..., 003..., etc.

As written, it works well if I have just ONE pair in my source directory, but I do not know what to do to make it iterate through in a pairwise fashion.

```
set path=%path%;C:\userbin\gdal;
mkdir single_band
for %%i in (*.tif) do gdal_translate -b 1 -of "gtiff" -co "tfw=yes" -a_srs "epsg:26717" %%i .\single_band\B1_%%~ni.tif 
for %%i in (*.tif) do gdal_translate -b 2 -of "gtiff" -co "tfw=yes" -a_srs "epsg:26717" %%i .\single_band\B2_%%~ni.tif
for %%i in (*.tif) do gdal_translate -b 3 -of "gtiff" -co "tfw=yes" -a_srs "epsg:26717" %%i .\single_band\B3_%%~ni.tif
cd /single_band
for /f "delims=_. tokens=1-6" %%i in ('dir /b *.t??') do ren %%i_%%j_%%k_%%l_%%m.%%n %%i_%%m.%%n
gdalbuildvrt -separate -overwrite 4bandout_IRGB.vrt B1_NIR.tif B1_RGB.tif B2_RGB.tif B3_RGB.tif
mkdir 4band
gdal_translate -of "gtiff" -co "tfw=yes" -a_srs "epsg:26717" 4bandout_IRGB.vrt .\4band\IRGB.tif
del *.t??
```

.......
With the help of mihai_mandis answer (THANKS!):

```
for %%i in (*NIR.tif) do (
set RGBName=%%i
set RGBName=!RGBName:NIR=RGB!
echo %%i,!RGBName! >>.\single_band\RGBNIR_list.txt
```

I get a .txt list:

> 001_x_y_NIR.tif,001_x_y_RGB.tif
>   002_a_b_NIR.tif,002_a_b_RGB.tif
>   etc...

I would love to be able to call to this .txt. list and iterate through it line by line, pair by pair to execute my process creating my outputs for the first pair, deleting my intermediate files and then moving onto the second pair, etc.

Also, in order to not overwrite my outputs, I'd like to carry the leading three digit identifiers through to my final product as XXX_IRGB.tif...Any other thought?

Thanks

Comment: Is it mandatory that it be batch? If you're starting out new with the console/command line in Windows, you ought to give PowerShell a look, as it's the way forward.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code bellow ti iterate through files and get both file names (RGB and NIR) in the same iteration.
You can use these filenames to call your command as desired.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%i in (*NIR.tif) do (
    rem %%i is the NIR file name
    set RGBName=%%i
    set RGBName=!RGBName:NIR=RGB!
    echo "%%i" "!RGBName!"
)
```